# PhantomJSDriver is not auto-redirecting to a URL

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, identityserver2

I have written an automation test using Selenium with C#.

When I am using Chrome driver to automate test then it's working as expected. Code are as below:

```
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://de.buyvip.com/");
```

When I am using PhantomJS driver to automate the same test then it's not working as expected. Code are as below:

```
 IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://de.buyvip.com/");
```

In Chrome driver, when a user tries to navigate https://de.buyvip.com/ then a user is automatically navigated to the login page.

But in a case of PhantomJSDriver when a user tries to navigate https://de.buyvip.com/ then a user remains on the same page and not automatically redirected to the login page.

Comment: I've run into the same problem..